# shmget() returns ENOENT with IPC_CREAT

Tags: linux, memory, pthreads, mutex, shared

I'm using `shmget()` to allocate a shared memory segment that I then use with `pthread_mutex_init()` to create a mutex shared between processes.  Generally, this works  as expected.  However, occasionally `shmget()` will return `ENOENT`.  Reading the man page, this should only occur if the `shmflg` doesn't include `IPC_CREAT`, however I am including that.  Here's a snip-it of my code:

```
shmid_ = shmget( MYLOCK_KEY_ID, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t), IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666 );
if ( errno == ENOENT ) {
    // This should never occur since IPC_CREAT was specified
    std::cerr
       << "shmget() returned ENOENT (it thinks IPC_CREAT wasn't  specified).\n"
       << "This seems to be a bug in shmget()?" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

I'm totally lost as to what could be going on.  I've tried this on several systems (Linux kernels 2.6.32 and 3.3.5) but both exhibit the same behavior.  Currently, when I obtain this failure mode, I just repeat the process and it usually works.  But that seems kind of kludgey and I don't know if this is a bug in `shmget()` or if I'm just doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is not checking the returned value - the man pages say to check shmid_ for -1 and then check errno.

```
RETURN VALUE 
A valid segment identifier, shmid, is returned on success, -1 on error.
```

What you are doing is just checking errno - it could be ENOENT after some other call to some other function that failed.

Comment: Right you are.  Thanks for helping me catch that!